How to make the upgrading from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 work?
Launching update-manager:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo update-manager -c

I get "Software updates are not longer provided for Ubuntu 23.10. You should upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS":

Clicking  "Upgrade..." I get :
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo update-manager -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

Tried then to fully upgrade:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.1 gir1.2-snapd-2 gir1.2-webkit2-4.1 grub-common grub-efi- 
amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc
  grub-pc-bin grub2-common libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3     
libavahi-glib1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0

raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
After this operation, 28,7 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 452915 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 (12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1) ...

libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp-server2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0 libminiupnpc17
libnatpmp1 libsnapd-glib-2-1 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0 libwinpr2-2 mobile-broadband-provider-info remmina-common
transmission-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
raphy@raohy:~$
But executing again update-manager gives the same output:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo update-manager
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before    
upgrading.

How to make the upgrading from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 work?
Update 1)
I followed the indications found here: How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu? , and managed to upgrade Ubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04
But now on the screen everything is "oversized" and "out of scale" :

How to make the desktop's appearance normal again?

apt full-upgrade does NOT change your release ; it applies all upgrades available for your EXISTING release.  Did you read the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS release notes; and upgrade instructions (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades)  though I'd start with the Release notes first.. as they list all QA testing issues discovered & provide the mitigations for any problems

@guiverc here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades it says to run the update-manager, the step I've already done few times, as described in my post above

Your details do NOT show you attempting the upgrade at all; you only CHECK (you use the -c option or CHECK option!) for the upgrade, but never actually try to use it.   (and I looked and see no mention of -c in the NobleUpgrades link ; what you have pasted in this question differs to that doc)

@guiverc With sudo update-manager without any -c option I have the same issue. I updated my post above

Did you run Sudo apt Update and  sudo apt upgrade before trying?

@amar  I upgraded Ubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04
But now on the screen everything is "oversized" and "out of scale" ( I updated my post above). There must be something related to screen management

Or something about your gpu driver. I never upgrade, just copy everything I want someplace else and just do a clean installation, it is a lot less hassle.

You have totally changed the meaning of your question. Please edit it to focus on only one problem.

Thanks @amar . I opened a new question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521454/screen-and-visualization-issue-after-upgrading-from-23-10-to-24-04

Simple solution:
I purged all the NVIDIA drivers files I had following: https://github.com/oddmario/NVIDIA-Ubuntu-Driver-Guide?tab=readme-ov-file  :
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt autoremove
reboot

And no screen issue anymore

Thank you everybody for your kind help. Appreciated
