Screen and visualization issue after upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04: a gpu driver issue?
I upgraded Ubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04
But now on the screen everything is "oversized" and "out of scale" :

There must be something to fix about the screen management
Is it a gpu driver issue?
What can I do to fix it?

Simple solution:
I purged all the NVIDIA drivers files I had following: https://github.com/oddmario/NVIDIA-Ubuntu-Driver-Guide?tab=readme-ov-file  :
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt autoremove
reboot

And no screen issue anymore
